# Seat ibiza 6K2: How to operate the ventilation without a car radio

Tags: electrical, fan, seat-ibiza

I'm facing a challenge with my 2002 Seat Ibiza 6K2. I'd like to remove the factory radio unit entirely, but I'm concerned about how it might affect the ventilation system.

Has anyone successfully tackled this issue or can provide guidance on how to maintain proper ventilation after removing the original radio? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!